# Can anyone identify the name of this font or a closer looking font? i am working on a project & am failing to identify the font name

Tags: fonts

can anyone please identify the  font name[image: can anyone please identify the 2 font names below] below

Comment: Knowing the source would be good to narrow down the search. Country? Date?

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be [Marcelle Script](https://www.dafont.com/marcelle.font?text=Evarist)!

[image]

Comment: Strange how it's almost a perfect match, but with a few small differences like the dot over the i and a different grunge texture. Why do both fonts have grunge texture?!?